# XML visualization by mxGraph (www.jgraph.com) from Java

Tags: java, xml

I would like to visialize XML-tree by mxGraph from Java.
Is it possible? How? Are there examples?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of XMLBeans to parse your XML. Then you can create the graph nodes using whichever displaying API (like mxGraph).